# Exception in thread "main" org.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at 1 [character 2 line 1]

Tags: java, json, url, bufferedreader

I am getting an error while reading the json data from URL. Below is the code what i am trying to.Please correct me where i am going wrong.

```
public class ReadingJsonData {
 public static void main(String[] args) throws JSONException {
 JSONObject json = readJsonFromUrl("http://requestb.in/pp1mzapp");
  }

public static JSONObject readJsonFromUrl(String url) throws IOException,  JSONException {
     InputStream is = new URL(url).openStream();
     try {
       BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,  Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
       String jsonText = readAll(rd);
       JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonText.trim());
       return json;
     } finally {
       is.close();
     }
    }

     private static String readAll(Reader rd) throws IOException {
       StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
       int cp;
       while ((cp = rd.read()) != -1) {
        sb.append((char) cp);
       }
       return sb.toString();
    }
     }
```

And my Json object from URL looks like

```
{"FormID":"2095180","UniqueID":"213482652","Name":{"first":"Something","last":"New"},"Date of Birth":"Feb 03, 1926","Last 4 Digits of SSN":"1234","Week Beginning Date":"Jan 01, 2012","Week Ending Date":"Feb 03, 2014","Email":"something.new@something.gov":""}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Json is not correct, see the last line

```
{
"FormID": "2095180",
"UniqueID": "213482652",
"Name": {
    "first": "Something",
    "last": "New"
},
"Date of Birth": "Feb 03, 1926",
"Last 4 Digits of SSN": "1234",
"Week Beginning Date": "Jan 01, 2012",
"Week Ending Date": "Feb 03, 2014",
"Email": "something.new@something.gov": ""
}
```

Comment: Thats a TYPO, I fixed it

Answer (score 0):

Actually what I get when opening this URL is "ok". That's the reason why it complains that your Json string doesn't start with a curly bracket.

Comment: Yes when i tried in difffrent way its just display's OK. But when you try open a page with "http://requestb.in/pp1mzapp" it shows the json objcet

Comment: You should print the contents of jsonText to the console to make sure that you're actually getting the Json string you expect.

Answer (score 0):

I see the issue, the URL what i am passing is getting the HTML page, entire page instead of  the response body that is the issue.